# How can I write a REST endpoint in Spring that just sends through the response from another API?

Tags: java, spring

I have a REST API, and then a webapp with a Spring backend. In the Spring backend, I want to create a route, let's call it `api-proxy/get-data`, which goes to the API at let's call it `api/get-data`, and whatever HTTP response it gets, it should just send it right through to the webapp front end. Right now my code looks something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/api-proxy/get-data/{id}",
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public ResponseEntity<String> getData(@PathVariable String id)
{
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String apiURL = "http://myapi.com/api/get-data/" + id;
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(apiURL, String.class);
    return response;
}
```

I thought this would work, but unfortunately when `RestTemplate.getForEntity` gets a 404, it doesn't return a `ResponseEntity` with a 404 status code, it throws an exception. So I would have to manually inspect the response and build a copy of it in a catch block - and also do that for 500 server errors, etc.

What's the correct way of getting the behavior I want in Spring? Whatever HTTP response I get from the upstream API, I want to send exactly that through to the client, headers and all. Almost like a proxy.

Comment: Have you tried forwarding request? Like this: `return "forward:http://myapi.com/api/get-data/" + id;`

Comment: @Lorelorelore I don't understand. If I just return that from this method, all that'll happen is my javascript client will receive that url as a string when it talks to my Spring server. What exactly is it you're saying I should do?

Comment: You can use  methods from java.net.HttpURLConnection;
and  java.net.URL to perform your request instead of restTemplate without dealing with exceptions

Comment: Sorry, wrong suggestion... what I suggested does not work for your case.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code , it will give you exception where you going wrong

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(Url, 
                                                        HttpMethod.GET, 
                                                        null, 
                                                        new ParameterizedTypeReference<String>>(){});

    if (response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
        return response.getBody();
    } else if (response.getStatusCode().is4xxClientError()) {
        throw new Exception("Exception while "+response.getBody());
    } else if (response.getStatusCode().is5xxServerError()) {
        throw new Exception("Bad request error "+response.getBody());
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Exception while querying service "+response.getBody()); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try another `RestTemplate` method. As I read in the javadoc [exchange](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-org.springframework.http.RequestEntity-java.lang.Class-):

> Execute the request specified in the given RequestEntity and return the response as ResponseEntity.

So you could try updating your code using this:

```
RequestEntity request = RequestEntity.get(new URI(apiURL));
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(apiURL, String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding your own error handler:

```
ResponseErrorHandler errorHandler = new ResponseErrorHandler() {

    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse clientHttpResponse) throws IOException {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse clientHttpResponse) throws IOException {
    }
};
```

And wire it like this:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
```

The errors won't be considered as errors and will just be forwarded to client.